# How can I distribute my java applications for user ease?

Tags: java, cross-platform, distribution

I'm really confused - but really it's pretty wierd because I know two programming langauges but I can't figure out something simple like this...
I've been looking for ages but I can't seem to get my head around it.
You See, for a long time I've been writting in **AutoIt**, and I've written two programs in it that are due to go on sale soon! They were never meant to be out for a long time though (kind of like Windows Vista), so lately I've been learning Java with success. I've wrote a few very very simple applications in **eclipse** while going through Java tutorials! I'm now ready to transfer my programs to Java, to gain me a wider market due to Java's cross-platform ability, but I never anticipated distribution to be this complex. 
My first problem I have come across is ease of use on multiple OS's: I don't want my customers to have to deal with JRE or multiple files, I need a double click solution that will work on MAC, Windows, Linux, etc so that even complete computer newbie's can launch my software! Secondly, this is not as much a problem as something I am not sure how to do. This is including files in my software package some need to stay seperate from the program but others could be compiled, but actually I suppose this can be worked around by an installer - which would probably be easier! And finally the other proram I made is stand - alone so it can work on USB sticks (which what it was designed for), now, how do you suppose I do this so it will launch on multiple opearating systems when it's plugged in without any hasle?

**Update :: Forgot to add :: My concerns about security**

I have read and from personal experience I know: how easy it is to decompile a .jar, and if there not protected properly read the source code! I know about obfuscation and I know I'll have legal back up but it just worries me. Even from the point of view that user may get the wrong first impretion of my software.

So to conclude in one sentace (*Please read above still*):
I need to be able to let people use my software written in Java by double clicking *e.g.* Like something made in AutoIt - a standard application i.e *.exe

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two routes you can take without needing any extra software involved.

The first is to just make an [executable jar (Java Archive) file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/).  Java automatically associates the .jar extension with the Java interpreter on most systems.  The JAR's [manifest file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) will tell it [which class to launch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) when you double-click it.

The second, less recommended route, is to make a [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) application, with a JNLP launcher file.  The is aimed more at applications distributed from web sites.

Comment: Of course, there still must be a JRE installed on the host environment.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your amazing fast response - much appriciated. I've read about executable jar files before and the thing that bothered me was that users have to have JRE installed! This may be to much of a struggle for the type of people my software is aimed at unless JRE can be installed automatically which some users may not like! Another thing that concerns me is security, I will/have updated my original post to explain;

Comment: @Andy: There are professional software packaging tools that can include the JRE and install it if necessary. Installer VISE is one such tool, searching on Google will probably yield others. I don't know how many computers don't have a JRE installed, it seems pretty common these days, I think some even include it in factory OS distributions. A vanilla Windows install probably wouldn't have it, but that's not as common now, it would seem.

Comment: @FrusteratedWithFormsDesigner: I thought about suggesting those, but I didn't think there were any that are cross-platform.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: I'm intreged now because I definatly need cross-platform! THAT WAS THE WHOLE POINT OF ME LEARNING JAVA! Can you maybe suggest your idea's on this and try and respond to my comment on Ivan Stepuk's post please!

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest the third way: write several platform-specific launch scripts for your application. For example, run.bat for Windows and run.sh for Linux. Inside every script write a command to run JRE with all the necessary parameters. You can also maintain some pre-launch checks (is JRE installed?) or some platform-specific actions in this scripts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply too. Your suggested way seems like the most simple but the messiest aswell. That is something I didn't want and some of the same issues as my previous comment still arise! I do admire rapidshare manager V2, if any of you use it, and I know it's written in Java so if anyone knows how rapidshare have done it please can you tell me!?